# undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass... why?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, undefined

rails guide example, click the button save post, console show this message:

> Started POST "/posts" for 127001  at 2013-12-25 22:42:04 +0800
>   Processing by PostsController#create as HTML   Parameters:
>   {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"CLalUww3gqnSlED0AWdou6P/U2qya
>   vPqDiBANQOuYgA=", "post"=>{"title"=>"11", "text"=>"22"},
>   "commit"=>"Save Post"}    (0.0ms)  begin transaction    (0.0ms) 
>   rollback transaction Redirected to http://    127001:3000/posts
>   Completed 302 Found in 16ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
>
> Started GET "/posts" for 127001 at 2013-12-25 22:42:04 +0800
>   Processing by PostsController#index as HTML   Rendered
>   posts/index.html.erb within layouts/application (15.6ms) Completed 500
>   Internal Server Error in 31ms
>
> ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `each' for
>   nil:NilClass):
>
> ```
>         <th>Text</th>
>         </tr>
>         <% @posts.each do |post| %>
> ```
>
> ======================================================

routes is correct,  why post is nil?  rails 4.0.2   ruby 2.0

Comment: Please show the code of `PostsController#index`.

Comment: thanks  i know the reason, i used post ,should be posts.but now new issue raise undefined method `title' for nil:NilClass

Answer (score 35, accepted):

In your posts controller, you need to define `@posts`, which, based on the error you haven't.

```
# app/controllers/posts_controller.rb
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @posts = Post.all
  end
end
```

As `@posts` is not defined calling `each` on it will generate `undefined method`each' for nil:NilClass`.

Comment: def index
   @post = Post.all
end                        the code exist   should be post or posts?

Comment: @user3134762, notice that you have singular `@post` in your index action but you are using plural `@posts` in your view.

Answer (score 13):

To explain more about this error whenerver you encounter

```
  undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass
```

The error clearly complaints that you're calling each method on something here(@posts) which is nil. That means you've not defined it in your controller. Since you didn't define it, that's why it is complaining undefined method for nil class.

Please makes sure to check whenever you call an instance variable from your view? you must have to define that in your controller to be accessible in views.

Sometimes you'll also get this error if you call a private method in your controller.

Answer (score 3):

Try replacing this:

```
<% @posts.each do |post| %>
```

**with**

```
<% Post.all.each do |post| %>
```

Comment: Hi @anosha-rehan , Can you expand this?

Comment: Hi @Jeremas, I'm sorry but I unfortunately don't have this particular project anymore

Comment: @anosha-rehan , No problem, Thanks!